# Set Text Color for textView Android

Tags: android, colors, textview

In the string.xml file i use the following tag

```
 <string name="CodeColor" >"#0000ff"</string>
```

If I use

```
 textview1.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

it works, but when I use

```
  textview1.setTextColor(TextViewStyles.this.getResources().getColor(R.string.CodeColor)); 

 or
 textview1.setTextColor(R.string.CodeColor);
```

it doen't work.
Any suggestions...

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to create a set of styles in your xml (regularly in res/values/styles.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="gray">#eaeaea</color>
    <color name="titlebackgroundcolor">#00abd7</color>
    <color name="titlecolor">#666666</color>
<resources>
```

In the layout files you can call to the colors or styles:

```
android:textColor="@color/titlecolor"
```

Checkout some examples:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I wanted to call those style not in xml,since I have to dynamically change the color of that textview

Comment: You should try like this:  textview1.setTextColor(R.color.CodeColor);

Comment: Thank you...Issue partially solved...Thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 15):

You can use

```
  textView1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor))
```

or

```
  textview1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

or

```
    textview1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

or

```
    textView1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
```

Answer (score 5):

This may be easier:

```
TextView textresult = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
textresult.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Comment: It's working. Easy to implemt. we have to import import this line android.graphics.Color; Thanks

Answer (score 1):

you should use `R.color.CodeColor`. you are using `R.string.CodeColor`.

Answer (score 1):

try set color like this may helps you

```
txt.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0, 87, 48));
```

this is different way but it can change color , here need Red,Green,Blue Code to pass

Answer (score 1):

I am basically just merging all the partially good answers.

You defined your color as a `String`, but AFAIK Android processes colors as `Itegers`.
So use the `Colors.xml` file (instead of `strings.xml`):
and refer to it in code as `R.color.CodeColor`.
<sub>(Moreover, I think, there is some naming convention that tells you to name these values all lowercase: `code_color` or `codecolor`)</sub>

Or you can define them as strings, but then you are need to make it an Integer: `Color.parseColor(R.string.code_color)`.

Answer (score 0):

Define colors in **colors.xml** file like that:

```
  <resources>
       <color name="CodeColor" >#0000ff</color>
  </resources>
```

Then use color whatever you like in your code using: **R.color.CodeColor**

Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

I tried something like:

textView.setTextColor(R.color.Red);