# How to set the selected text background color of TextView

Tags: java, android

Hello I am working on demo application where I need to set the yellow background color of selected text in a string.

For ex :

```
String str = "Na Adam ne ne yere Hawa: Na Adam xwoo xbabarima";
```

I want to set the white background color of all words except `Adam`. I need to set the background color of `Adam` word to yellow.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What type of output or GUI control are you displaying the text on?

Comment: probably a `spannable` will serve the purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following code:

```
        String str = "Na Adam ne ne yere Hawa: Na Adam xwoo xbabarima";
        String stringToColor = "Adam"; 
        int ofe = str.indexOf(stringToColor,0);   
        Spannable WordtoSpan = new SpannableString(str);

for(int ofs=0;ofs<str.length() && ofe!=-1;ofs=ofe+1)
{       


      ofe = str.indexOf(stringToColor,ofs);   
          if(ofe == -1)
              break;
          else
              {                       

              WordtoSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(Color.YELLOW), ofe, ofe+stringToColor.length(),Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
              textView.setText(WordtoSpan, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
              }


}
```

Output:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use some html:

```
String adam = "<font color=#FFFF00>Adam</font>";
String str = "Na Adam ne ne yere Hawa: Na Adam xwoo xbabarima";
String newString = str.replaceAll("Adam", adam);
t.setText(Html.fromHtml(newString));
```

Comment: Thanks. How to set the `adam` background yellow that I am looking ?

Comment: I guess with a simple String.replaceAll: http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Comment: @blackbelt Yeah You are correct. Can you please answer and how to set that text background color to yellow ?

Comment: I have edited it for yellow I think, the color is now `#FFFF00` which I believe is yellow, please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: +1 Thanks but this will set the text color not background. I want to set the background color. Any way to do that ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't think this is possible with the textView provided by Android, here is a list of the supported html tags and none of them support background highlighting: http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html

Answer (score 0):

You should look into the JEditorPane class, it allows you to do things like these easily:

```
JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html","<font color=\"red\">this will be red</font><font color=\"blue\">, and this will be blue</font>");
```

[image]

Comment: android has not javax.swing

Answer (score 0):

Look at this [question here on setting the color of a TextView.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12524920/set-text-color-for-textview-android)

You can use

```
textView1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.mycolor))
```

or

```
textview1.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

or

```
textview1.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

or

```
textView1.setBackgroundColor(R.color.black);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can format the text as HTML such as:

```
   String htmlText =  "<font color=#000000>Na </font> <font color=#00FF00>Adam </font> <font color=#000000>ne ne yere Hawa: Na </font> <font color=#00FF00>Adam </font> <font color=#000000>xwoo xbabarima</font>"

    tView.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlText))
```

In order to make it more dynamic you can add some regular expression functionality for identifying ur keywords which should be of a different color and create the HTML text

Answer (score 0):

This formatting would be suitable for JLabel:

```
JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>Na <font bgcolor='yellow'>Adam</font> ne ne yere Hawa: Na <font bgcolor='yellow'>Adam</font> xwoo xbabarima</html>");
```